# EC2 Instance Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

We have recently started using AWS free tier for our CRM product.

We are facing speed related issues currently, so we are planning to change EC2 Instance.

It's a dotnet based website, using ASP.Net, C#.net, Microsoft SQL server 2012, IIS 7 server.

It would be great if someone can suggest correct EC2 instance for our usage. We are planning to use t2.Medium and MS SQL Enterprise license, Route 53, 30 GB EBS Volume, CloudWatch, SES and SNS. Are we missing something here..? Also what would be the approximate monthly billing for this usage..?

Thanks in advance. Cheers!!

Comment: t1/t2.micros are tiny. For "correct EC2 instance", well, it depends. Are you CPU-bound? Memory-bound? Disk-bound? You can disproportionately expand in any direction on that. I do recommend that you use RDS for the database.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the scope of Stack Overflow, is very localized, requires knowledge of your specific stack, and any answers would be of limited value to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure what the issue is without some performance monitoring. If you haven't already, setup Cloudwatch monitors. Personally I like to use monitoring services like New Relic as they can dive deep into your system - to the stored procedure and ASP.NET code level to identify bottlenecks.

The primary reason for doing this is to identify if your instance is maxing out on CPU usage, memory usage, swapping to disk, or if your bottleneck is in your networking bandwidth.

That being said, as jas_raj mentioned, the t-series instances are burstable, meaning if you have steady heavy traffic, you won't get good use from them. They're better suited for occasional peaks in load.

The m-series will provide a more stable level of performance but, in some cases, can be exceeded in performance by a bursting t-series machine.  When I run CMS, CRM and similar apps in EC2, I typically start with an M3 instance.

There are some other things to consider as well.

1. Consider putting your DB on RDS or on a separate server with high performance EBS volumes (EBS optimized, provisioned IOPS, etc.).
2. If you can, separate your app and session state (as well as the data layer) so you can consider using smaller EC2 instances but scale them based on traffic and demand.

As you can imagine, there are a lot of factors that go into performance, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the pricing based on your options by using Amazon's [Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

Regarding your usage, I don't have a lot of experience on the Windows side with AWS but I would point out the fact the amount of CPU allocation on `t2` instances is based on [a credit system](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html). If that's acceptable to your usage fine, otherwise switch to a non `t2` instance for more deterministic CPU performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have good understandings about your application, I would suggest you check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html) for differences between instance types and selection suggestions.